# BASH script - return two specific values from JSON output using GREP

Tags: json, regex, bash, curl, grep

I have the following JSON output recieved from a google API call, im strugling with a grep to only store "lat" and "lng" values under "geometry"\"location", so i get an output like:

lat,long

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "",
               "short_name" : "",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kildegade",
               "short_name" : "Kildegade",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Horsens",
               "short_name" : "Horsens",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Denmark",
               "short_name" : "DK",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "8700",
               "short_name" : "8700",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Kildegade, 8700 Horsens, Denmark",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 55.863466,
               "lng" : 9.848784
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 55.86481498029149,
                  "lng" : 9.850132980291503
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 55.8621170197085,
                  "lng" : 9.847435019708499
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJG8X9xAVjTEYRGwL9QuNARJQ",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I reckon that i need to make a GREP call after the API KEY, but im kinda stuck, as i get output without any GREP, but nothing when applying any simple GREP.

```
adresse=$(curl -s "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Kildegade+8700+horsens+denmark"&key=GOOGLE API KEY")
```

Prior to this i've in some similar JSON output used:

```
| grep -B 1 "route" | awk -F'"' '/short_name/ {print $4}
```

But this don't fit into this output, and im just not that powerful in using GREP ;)

Any help would be really helpful, thanks ;)

Comment: Have you considered using a tool that knows how to parse json instead of `grep`, like `jq`?

Comment: Im not familiar with jq - can it be used together with curl ? im storing my output in a file for each line, and have a larger size of variables to run through...

Comment: I don't know what you're asking there.  You can do `curl ... | jq ...` if that's what you are asking

Comment: Ok thanks i will look into jq, thanks for pointing me in a direction none the less ;)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here, but suppose you want to extract lat and lng from that json: you can ust use jq ( https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ ) like the following: jq '.results[].geometry.location'  < input.json

Please note in the example above that I'm considering that the json is stored in an file called input.json

Comment: thanks will look into that, and you're right i only need lat,lng extracted from the JSON output

Comment: Thanks Rod Elias, got it working using your suggested jq usage ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jq (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor.

Suppose you want to extract `lat` and `lng` fields from your json sample.

You can then use something like `jq '.results[].geometry.location' < input.json`

Please note in the example above that I'm considering that your json is stored in an file called `input.json`, but you could just use `jq` after `curl` like this: `curl ... | jq ...`